# NSTimer - Non-blocking callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I'm somewhat new to objective-c. So, if my question or code looks odd, that would explain why. I have a NSTimer which is fired every 0.033 seconds.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(timerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The selector function looks like this:

```
BOOL running = false;
- (void) timerCallback
{
   if (running) {
    return;
   }
   running = true;
   //Do some stuff
   running = false;
}
```

Thing is, the function timerCallback has to be fired  at these intervals no matter what to maintain the sync. (skipping going into detail)

But... as it turns out, the timerCallback function causes the NSTimer to stop and wait for it to complete before resuming?

What options do I have to maintain the interval? Can the timerCallback function be executed in a separate thread? Are there better options than NSTimer? Perhaps a separate thread to begin with?

Comment: Do you mean that the timer is not getting called repeatedly?

Comment: If you aren't able to perform the action in `timerCallback` within your timer interval then won't you create a backlog of "work" to do which will ultimately cause you problems?

Comment: No, it is. I mean, if the timerCallback requires 0.1 seconds, the NSTimer will stop, wait for the function to be completed, then resume. As a result, I loose sync. I need to keep the 0.033 second interval at all times.

Comment: @trojanfoe - No, I have no issues skipping one or two timerCallback calls. But I really need to maintain the interval. More important than executing the code.

Comment: What about if the timerCallback dispached a new thread?
and then call your code in that thread.

Comment: @geminiCoder - Yes, something like that would work. How would I implement that?

Comment: @geminiCoder Sounds expensive to create a new thread every 0.033 seconds...

Comment: good point. What run loop are you adding the timer to?

Comment: @geminiCoder Run loop as in NSTimeInterval? If so, the actual interval is 20 / 600 which is something like 0.0333333 seconds.

Comment: I assumed you were using [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addTimer:timer forMode:mode] why dont you try it in a different runloop, (possily in a different thread).

Comment: Will read up on this. (fairly new to objective-c so it's the first time I hear about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer will attempt to maintaing the desired firing interval averaged over time - since it cannot provide exact timing due to the design of NSTimer and NSRunLoop. If your code in he timer is taking over 0.033 seconds, I'm not sure if the timer will skip one call or not - it might

Try this experiment - set the timer, then comment out all your work, and log the time. It should be very close to the desired time. That said, at 30 calls a second, if you are touching the UI at all this is close to the maximum performance you could expect to get.

One strategy to minimize the amount of variation is to put all the code you are doing inside a block, and dispatch it either to the main queue, or better yet, dispatch it to a concurrent thread. That way you will return from the call in a very short period of time.

If this does not do if for you, look at CADisplayLink. You can get very precise callback using this capability, as it runs at a very high priority. However, you cannot do anything substantial in the callback as you only get a sliver of time. You can however dispatch blocks to a queue for processing on the main queue (main thread).

Comment: Implemented a dispatch_queue_t which seems to solve the issue for now. Will need to see which is the least expensive method later on.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like this, to prevent blocking.

```
BOOL running = false;
- (void) timerCallback
{
   if (running) {
    return;
   }

  [(NSOperationQueue*)_myOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
     running = true;
     //do Some Stuff
     running = false 
  }];
}
```

Comment: Implemented a dispatch_queue_t which seems to solve the issue for now. Will compare with this method to see which one is the least expensive.

Comment: In this code the blocks would be running concurrently, so you'd want to use a __block OSAtomic (see man 3 atomic) flag to set and clear a "running" flag. The running thing is sort of a red herring in the original code, as I don't believe NSTimer won't "stack" callbacks.